# Grails print each in attribute[]: [1,2,3]

Tags: grails

Below, is what returning on my server:

```
[test[]:[1, 2, 3, 4, 5], action: something, controller: myController]
```

And I can't `println` using

```
params.test.each{ println it}
```

How can I print on each element in test[]?

Comment: What happens if you `println params.test`? What about `println params.list('test')`?

Comment: `params."test[]".each { println it }`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue you are having is that the key named `test[]` needs to be escaped.

Thus you should be able to do:

```
params."test[]".each { println it }
```

The reason for needing to use double or single quotes around the property name is due to the fact you have brackets in the name of the property. Usually brackets appearing in Groovy code would be seen as a collection and without an index or key within the brackets it's considered invalid syntax.

So, in this case since the name of the property/key within your `params` contains brackets you need to wrap it in quotes so Groovy understands it's just part of the name/key and not an attempt to access it as a collection (even if your property is actually a collection).

Honestly, I would fix the root of the issue, meaning don't name your property `test[]` but rather `test` since it's much cleaner and clearer as to what your property actually is.

Comment: why using double quotes?

Comment: oh, now I see... usually I always did `params.test.each`, and this `[]` was the first time I see it.